# How to merge two Hex numbers to one number and then convert it into decimal.?

Tags: c, merge, numbers, hex, decimal

I am making a C program in which I have two hex numbers, i.e. `num1=25` `num2=71` which are in hex. I want to make it as `num3=2571` and then I have to convert `2571` into a decimal number. How do I do this? Please help, Thanks!

Comment: which language? c++,js,...

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention it , I am using C

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just shift the digits and combine

```
int num1,num2,num3;
num1=0x25;
num2=0x71;
num3=(num1<<8)|(num2);
printf("%x %d",num3,num3);
```

You need to place 25 (0025) followed by 71 (0071) in a variable, so you have to left shift the first number by 8 bits (0025 to 2500) and combine it with num2. Logical Or is the equivalent for combining, hence the `|` symbol.

Comment: This works :)  but there's no need for &: num3= ((num1<<8)|(num2));

Comment: ya.. I have made the change thanks    @MarianoMacchi

Comment: You need to place 25 (0025) followed by 71 (0071) in  a variable, so you have to left shift the first number by 8 bits (0025 to 2500) and combine num2 .Logical or is the equivalent for combining, hence the `| ` symbol.

Comment: Excellent! Answer

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are not stored as "decimal" or "hexadecimal", that is how they are written for humans to see. Assigning a value such as hexadecimal `num1 = 0x25` or as decimal `num1 = 37` makes no difference: `num1` will hold the same value.

```
num3 = 256 * num1 + num2;
```

Your question hasn't said what you would want to happen if the two hexadecimal humbers are `25` and `7`. Would the answer be `2507` or `257`? If the latter,

```
num3 = 16 * num1 + num2;
```

In either case, the corollary of my first paragraph applies: numbers aren't "decimal" or "hexadecimal" until you print them.

```
printf ("Decimal %d", num3);
printf ("Hexadecimal %x", num3);
```

The question makes more sense if the two numbers are strings - in human readable format!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char num1[] = "25";
    char num2[] = "71";
    char num[20];
    int num3;
    strcpy (num, num1);
    strcat (num, num2);
    printf ("Hexadecimal string %s\n", num);
    sscanf(num,"%x", &num3);
    printf ("Decimal number %d\n", num3);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Hexadecimal string 2571
Decimal number 9585
```